# Why RegExp split() and match() give different results?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
s = '<w:p>abc<w:p z="asd">123<w:p/>qwe<w:paa>asd</w:p>zxc'

x = new RegExp('<w:p( +[^>]*>|>|/>)','g')
console.log(s.match(x))
console.log(s.split(x))
```

*The output is:*

```
[ '<w:p>', '<w:p z="asd">', '<w:p/>' ]
[ '',
  '>',
  'abc',
  ' z="asd">',
  '123',
  '/>',
  'qwe<w:paa>asd</w:p>zxc' ]
```

Why the `match()` matches whole expression `<w:p( +[^>]*>|>|/>)`, but `split()` matches only the first part of the expression, which is `<w:p`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference in result is due to captured group in your regex. If you use non-capturing groups then both will behave same:

```
x = new RegExp('<w:p(?: +[^>]*>|>|/>)','g')
```

Now `split` will give:

```
console.log(s.split(x))
//=> ["", "abc", "123", "qwe<w:paa>asd</w:p>zxc"]
```

Reason is that `split` also places all matched groups in the output array.

**PS:** Your regex can be simplified to:

```
x = /<w:p( +[^>]*>|\/?>)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = new RegExp('<\/?w:p[^>]*>', 'g')
```

gives

```
console.log(s.match(x)) == ["<w:p>", "<w:p z="asd">", "<w:p/>", "<w:paa>", "</w:p>"]

console.log(s.split(x)) == ["", "abc", "123", "qwe", "asd", "zxc"]
```